# Unable to change system variable path in Windows 10 as an Admin

Tags: java, windows

I am installing Java JDK in Windows 10 machine that requires registering its path by editing System Variables in Windows settings, but I tried both as an admin and regular user and it doesn't allow me to add the path, even copy paste or just adding any character.I have no trouble doing this in Win 8 until I am 'tempted' to avail and run free upgrade by Microsoft.

*Q1:*

Is this A bug in Windows 10? I update my machine regularly and also auto update is turned on to ensure to get the latest fix from Microsoft. Kaspersky is also disabled temporarily.

*Q2:*

How do you edit the system variable in Win 10 machine? I am planning to downgrade my Machine to windows 7 or 8 if this issue is not fixed.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say it won't allow you set the path, how did you try to do it? What command or menu option did you try to use?

Comment: Also, what happened?  Was there an error message?  Did it just not seem to work?  Did you remember to reboot the machine after making the change?

Comment: What I mean is I cant edit the system variable path.I have no trouble in Win 7 or 8.You cant type any characters when editing the path, even if you have the admin credentials.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you cant edit system variable under Path in windows 10, try this instead

[image]

Login as administrator

go to your Java folder e.g

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\bin and copy.
```

Now in search box beside windows logo at the bottom type

```
path
```

and select the one that says

```
'edit the system environment variables'
```

This is important, select 'New' tab in User variables for Administrator, not the 'New' tab from 'System variables' as you cant edit it.Now name it as you wish, mine is PATH.Now copy and paste the path where you installed Java, mine is under

```
 c:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\bin
```

Hit ok to exit.

Restart your command line and test Java

```
 java -version
```

it should tell you java version and Java is successfully installed and accessible.Start using it and cheers

Answer (score 15):

I was also facing the same issue.

When you search with "Environment Variable" you will get two result

[image]

- Click on the second option (2) "Edit the system environment variable".
- Once you select option 2, you will get a popup where you need to click on "Environment Variables" as below screen.

[image]

Now you can change variables (user & system variables) as per your requirement. You are done here!

Below is more detail about those two options

1. **Environment Variable for your account** - This will only allow you to change the "user variable". system variable will be disabled.
2. **Edit the system environment variable** - With this option, you can change both (user or system variables). Once you select this option, you will get a popup where you need to click on "Environment Variables".

Answer (score 7):

When I was trying to add a new path to my system variables, I was unable to select the edit button. To get to system variables I went to my search bar and selected "edit environmental variables for your account." When i did this, the edit button was grayed out and I couldn't add a new path. 
To fix this i typed in my search bar and selected "edit the system environment variables" once that box comes up right above the ok button select "click environmental variables". Yay, the path edit button is no longer grayed out. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

I got around it by opening the System page in Control Panel (Win+X -> Y), going to "Advanced system settings", then clicking "Environment Variables". That properly launches the edit window and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced similar problem after installation of new JDK and following steps resolved the issue:-

1. Copy the entire content of path System variable in notepad and see
   if there is any path related to Java.
2. Delete all the path related to Java.
3. Click Ok.
4. Now you can edit the Path without any issue.

If these steps doesn't work than you can create a new Variable.

Answer (score 0):

My situation is a bit different as I use a small 7" windows tidy notebook called "one-notebook (One MIX)".  It seems the "OK" key is not shown in the 2nd stage in horizontal position and you need to rotate the screen to see the OK.  Spend a lunch time for that.

Answer (score -1):

There is a simple solution if your global environment variables are disabled.
Follow these steps to open it in admin mode:

1. <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.
2. <kbd>Y</kbd>.
3. Search Advance System Settings and open it.
4. Now select environment variables.