# Restore a postgres backup file using the command line\shell in Win10

Tags: sql, postgresql, backup

I can't restore backup, I'm using this query:

```
psql -h <localhost> -U <Username> -d <Name_of_database> -f <Name_of_disk:\name of backup file.sql>
```

In case when I type this query  in CommandLine I have message:"'psql' is not recognized as an internal or external command" and all is stopped.

In case when I type this query in SQLShell I have message : "Invalid command (there stored part of path to backup.sql). Try \? for help." and all is stopped.

Comment: "*is not recognized as an internal or external command*" simply means the Postgres `bin` directory is not part of your [path](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34116833/330315)

Comment: thanks, all working =)